# How to set a cookie based on a page Get variable?

Tags: php, cookies

I am trying to set a cookie, based on a GET variable from a page.

The page URL looks like: `mysite.com/?my_var=somevalue`

I'm trying this, but can't see what I'm doing wrong..

```
// make 'my_var' available as get_query_var('my_var')..
function add_query_vars_filter($vars){
    $vars[] = "my_var";
    return $vars;
}
add_filter('query_vars', 'add_query_vars_filter');

add_action('init', 'my_setcookie');

// take the query_var 'my_var' and set it as cookie 'my_cookie'
function my_setcookie() {
    setcookie('my_cookie', get_query_var('my_var'), strtotime('+1 day'));
}
```

Would love a little help with this!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Setcookie works on admin but not front end](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/138644/setcookie-works-on-admin-but-not-front-end)

Comment: You want to set cokkie on every page wherever you get that `my_var` or on specific page like homepage or post page. :)

Comment: Thanks G.M. - I'll try that - looks as though it may work for this..

Comment: Thanks ksr89 - I just want to set it for one specific page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the page where you want to set the `cookie` write this code and check

```
if(get_query_var('my_var') == 'somevalue'){
    setcookie('my_cookie', get_query_var('my_var'), strtotime('+1 day'));
}
```

If we go with your code then it will set `coookie` on every page who having query variable

`?my_var=somevalue`

Comment: Thanks ksr89 - that works, as long as I can edit the page template for that page, to set the cookie before any output.. However, I don't want to use a custom edited template page, so I think so I think I am limited to either a plugin (beyond my skills..), or site-wide functions available in the functions.php - So I did a combination of yours and the page that G. M. mentioned: